# How do I convert plaintext to a String in php?

Tags: php

What I want to do is get the number of pages for the html file, I already got the section that I want but I can't gat the numbers alone.

```
<?php
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
error_reporting(E_ERROR);

$html = file_get_html('http://www.seccionamarilla.com.mx/resultados/hospitales/distrito-federal/1');
foreach($html->find('.paginas',0) as $e){

//echo $e->plaintext;
$res = $e->plaintext;
$text = (string)$res;
echo $res."<br>";
echo $text."<br>";
echo substr($text, 10);

}

?>
```

I am using the yellowpages as an example. This are the results i'm getting.

```
Resultados (3892) PÃ¡gina 1 -  2 -  3 -  4 -  5   
Resultados (3892) PÃ¡gina 1 -  2 -  3 -  4 -  5   
Resultados (3892) PÃ¡gina 1 -  2 -  3 -  4 -  5
```

I have tried the substr() but it has no effect on it. The only thing I want is the number 3892. Also i would like to get rid of the lines before the output is completed. It goes through the loop and prints nothing for 4 or 5 lines and 3 after the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$html = file_get_html('http://www.seccionamarilla.com.mx/resultados/hospitales/distrito-federal/1');
$results=$html->find('div.folios div.paginas',0)->plaintext;
preg_match('/\((\d+)\)/',$results, $matches);
$pages=(int)$matches[1];
echo $pages;
```